# перетаскивание текста в редакторе Brackets

Tags: редактор, adobe-brackets

В таких текстовых редакторах, как **Sublime Text** и 
**Notepad++** есть возможность перетаскивать текст. Например, Вы выделяете участок текста, нажимаете на клавишу **Ctrl** и мышкой перетаскиваете его в нужное место, при этом текст копируется. Если не нажимать клавишу **Ctrl**, то текст не копируется, а перемещается. В редакторе **Brackets** это не происходит.

Возможно ли в настройках редактора **Brackets** сделать какие либо изменения, что бы происходило перетаскивание? Если да, то напишите эту настройку.

Comment: Посоветовал бы Вам в Stack Overflow на английском продублировать вопрос. Здесь даже нет метки [tag:Brackets], почему участники, разбирающиеся в этом редакторе, могут не увидеть Ваш вопрос. (Сам пользуюсь Sublime Text). Спасибо.

Comment: Здравствуйте Саша Черных! Я в английском языке еще на примитивном уровне. Поэтому, мой вопрос носители этого языка будут долго расшифровывать.

Comment: У меня тоже с английским нелады, пользуюсь [QTranslate](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=5&bm=1&topic=35038#1), выбирая из вариантов перевода от PROMT, Babylon или Google Translate. Вроде понимают и отвечают :) . Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Давайте добавим эту метку?

Comment: @KromStern, я только за. 2 поправки: 1) метка [tag:brackets] кем-то [добавлена](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brackets), но не синонимизирована с [tag:adobe-brackets];  2) возможно, основной меткой стоит сделать именно [tag:brackets], а не [tag:adobe-brackets] по причине большей узнаваемости. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных эту метку я добавил а потом переименовал аналогично английскому SO. Вопрос о синонимизации и выборе основной ты можешь поднять на Мете.

Comment: @KromStern, [**OK**](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2917/199934). Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Отладка*** / ***Открыть файл настроек***

```
"dragDropText": true
```